What's a good way to notify ScrolledComposite to make adjustments?
When ScrolledComposite's content changes, we can call the ScrolledComposite.setMinSize() method to adjust the ScrollBars of the ScrolledComposite. For example:
Shell shell = new Shell() ;
shell.setSize( 300, 200 ) ;
shell.setLayout( new FillLayout() ) ;

ScrolledComposite sc = new ScrolledComposite( shell, SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.BORDER ) ;
sc.setExpandHorizontal( true ) ;
sc.setExpandVertical( true ) ;

Composite content = new Composite( sc, SWT.NONE ) ;
sc.setContent( content ) ;

content.setLayout( new GridLayout() ) ;

Button button = new Button( content, SWT.NONE ) ;
button.setText( "Add a Button" ) ;
button.addListener( SWT.Selection, e -> {
    Button btn = new Button( content, SWT.NONE ) ;
    btn.setText( "" + System.currentTimeMillis() ) ;
    btn.requestLayout() ;
    
    sc.setMinSize( content.computeSize( SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT ) ) ;
} ) ;

shell.open() ;

However, if ScrolledComposite and content are created in two separate classes, the content side may not even know that the parent is ScrolledComposite, so how can it notify the ScrolledComposite side to make adjustments?  For example:
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Test().execute() ;
}

class Test {
    
    void execute() {
        Shell shell = new Shell() ;
        shell.setSize( 300, 200 ) ;
        shell.setLayout( new FillLayout() ) ;
        
        A a = new A() ;
        ScrolledComposite sc = a.createControl( shell ) ;
        
        B b = new B() ;
        Control content = b.createContent( sc ) ;
        sc.setContent( content ) ;
        
        shell.open() ;
    }
    
}

class A {
    
    ScrolledComposite createControl( Composite parent ) {
        ScrolledComposite sc = new ScrolledComposite( parent, SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.BORDER ) ;
        sc.setExpandHorizontal( true ) ;
        sc.setExpandVertical( true ) ;
        
        return sc ;
    }
    
}

class B {
    
    Control createContent( Composite parent ) {
        Composite content = new Composite( parent, SWT.NONE ) ;
        content.setLayout( new GridLayout() ) ;
        
        Button button = new Button( content, SWT.NONE ) ;
        button.setText( "Add a Button" ) ;
        button.addListener( SWT.Selection, e -> {
            Button btn = new Button( content, SWT.NONE ) ;
            btn.setText( "" + System.currentTimeMillis() ) ;
            btn.requestLayout() ;
        } ) ;
        
        return content ;
    }
    
}

As above, class A and class B may be far apart and unaware of each other's existence.
The e4 event might be a way to do this, with the event being published in B and subscribed to and handled in A.
However, this seems a bit strange. A change in content can be notified to the ScrolledComposite via requestLayout(), so why not handle it in the ScrolledCompositeLayout.

Why does your listener keep adding buttons, all of them as well as the first without GridData layout data set onto them?

This is just an example, in real scenarios the controls in the content will change dynamically due to user actions and need to adjust the scrollbars in real time. GridData If you don't set it, a default GridData will be set for the control in the GridLayout layout.

Things like the forms ExpandableComposite just go up the chain of parent controls looking for ScrolledComposite

Do you mean  looking for ScrolledComposite in class B ?
